# What is the proper way to retrieve a token after it’s been registered?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic-cloud

After your push token has been registered, what is the proper way to retrieve the token again for future use?

Previously, you were able to call a getStorageToken() function to retrieve the saved token on the device. With the new $ionicCloud method, it does not appear as if that is an option.

Can someone point me in the right direction for a better understanding of how to get an already saved token on the device?

Thanks!

Comment: after you register the token , you can get it immeditely as shown here http://docs.ionic.io/services/push/#registering-device-tokens

Comment: @Akil thanks for the reply. That is the way I am registering and grabbing the token upon registration. However, I am looking for a solution to get the token later, after it's already been registered. I grab the token from the device when my splash screen is shown. I'd like get the token again within another section of the app. Any thoughts?

Comment: you could save the token in your server and retrieve it later, or just save it in local storage like this: localStorage.setItem(token.toString());   And retrieve it later

Answer (score 0):

It appears that I was making this far too difficult.

I simply used the code `$ionicPush.token.token` to access to the token after it was registered.